# Record data from specific command using Neurosky device

Tags: c#

I was trying to record the raw data using Neurosky device and I managed to do so. But I need to write a command (for example move your right arm) then record the data for that command but the problem is that OnDataReceived event is fired all the time and I don't know where can I add some code for the command before recording the data. Any help? 
My code:

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;

using NeuroSky.ThinkGear;
using NeuroSky.ThinkGear.Algorithms;
using System.Collections;

namespace testprogram
{
    class Program
    {

        static Connector connector;
        static HeartRateAcceleration heartRateAcceleration;
        static HeartRateRecovery heartRateRecovery;

        static byte poorSig;
        static int train;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Hello EEG!");

            // Initialize a new Connector and add event handlers
            connector = new Connector();
            connector.DeviceConnected += new EventHandler(OnDeviceConnected);
            connector.DeviceConnectFail += new EventHandler(OnDeviceFail);
            connector.DeviceValidating += new EventHandler(OnDeviceValidating);

            Connector.EKGPersonalizationEvent += new EventHandler(OnEKGPersonalizationEvent);

            heartRateRecovery = new HeartRateRecovery();
            heartRateAcceleration = new HeartRateAcceleration();

            // Scan for devices
            connector.ConnectScan("COM40");

            // Enable Energy level calculation
            // connector.StartEnergyLevel();
            //connector.GetHeartAge(90, "Neraj");

            connector.EKGstartLongTraining("Neraj");

            Thread.Sleep(450000);

            //Console.WriteLine(connector.GetHeartRiskAware("Neraj"));
            //Console.WriteLine(connector.GetHeartAgeStatus("Neraj"));
            //Console.WriteLine(connector.ResetHeartAge("Neraj"));

            System.Console.WriteLine("Goodbye.");

            // Close all open connections
            connector.Close();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        static void OnEKGPersonalizationEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            EKGPersonalizationEventArgs ekgArgs = (EKGPersonalizationEventArgs)(e);
            int status = ekgArgs.statusMessage;

            switch (status)
            {
                case 268:
                    string data = (string)(ekgArgs.dataMessage);
                    Console.WriteLine("Handler Message: status = MSG_EKG_IDENTIFIED " + " and username = " + data);
                    break;

                case 269:
                    Console.WriteLine("Handler Message: status = MSG_EKG_TRAINED");

                    connector.EKGstartDetection();
                    break;

                case 270:
                    int trainStep = (int)ekgArgs.dataMessage;
                    Console.WriteLine("Handler Message: status = MSG_EKG_TRAIN_STEP " + " and training step = " + trainStep);
                    break;

                case 271:
                    Console.WriteLine("Handler Message: status = MSG_EKG_TRAIN_TOUCH");
                    break;
            }
        }


        /**
         * Called when a device is connected 
         */
        static void OnDeviceConnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Connector.DeviceEventArgs de = (Connector.DeviceEventArgs)e;

            Console.WriteLine("Device found on: " + de.Device.PortName);

            de.Device.DataReceived += new EventHandler(OnDataReceived);
        }

        /**
         * Called when scanning fails
         */
        static void OnDeviceFail(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No devices found! :(");
        }

        /**
         * Called when each port is being validated
         */
        static void OnDeviceValidating(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Validating: ");

            heartRateRecovery.enableHeartRateRecovery();
        }

        /**
         * Called when data is received from a device
         */
        static void OnDataReceived(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Device d = (Device)sender;
            Device.DataEventArgs de = (Device.DataEventArgs)e;
            DataRow[] tempDataRowArray = de.DataRowArray;

            TGParser tgParser = new TGParser();
            tgParser.Read(de.DataRowArray);

            /* Loop through new parsed data */
            ArrayList data = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < tgParser.ParsedData.Length; i++)
            {
                if (tgParser.ParsedData[i].ContainsKey("Raw"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Raw Value:" + tgParser.ParsedData[i]["Raw"]);
                    data.Add(tgParser.ParsedData[i]["Raw"]);
                }
            }
            AnalyizeData(data);
        }

        private static void AnalyizeData(ArrayList data)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is missing a block so it doesn't close.  You r using a Sleep(4500000) instead.  You need a while loop in the main() method that check if data send data is available.  Replace the sleep with a while and then add code to send inside the while loop.

Comment: but it will never go to the main again as the OnDataReceived event is called continuously.

Comment: That is not true.   When the Receive event completes it will return to main until next event occurs.  In the present code you don't see that because it is returning to the Sleep(450000) and doing nothing.

Comment: yes .. but the event occurs at all time

Comment: Yes the event occurs constantly, but there is time between one event finishing and the next occurring.  On you  computer you have lots of event that is constantly occurring and the scheduler allows task switching so all the processes are running simultaneously.  The OnDataReceive Event and the Main() method in your code are two of these tasks that the scheduler is handling.